# clang compile failed on mariadb

Tags: c++, clang, mariadb

system is CentOS(VirtualBox) x64
I had "yum install" and "yum check" cmake clang gcc libstdc++ and compat-libstdc++*
I had link cmake to clang
I had compile a "HelloWorld" program by clang successed

then,
I try to compile mariadb'code use : "cmake . -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release".
I got error like this:
...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/clang++" is not able to compile a simple test
  program. 
...  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ 
... 

How can I fix this problem? Thanks very much!
（Please forgive me for my poor English T_T）

Comment: Getting libstdc++-devel, etc. etc. **c++** : # `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: Yes! I missing a package name "gcc-c++" before. I thought the package "gcc" both contain c lib and c++ lib ... orz

Comment: hello  Knud Larsen ~~ you can move your anwser from "comment" to "answer" so that i can "accept" it.

Comment: `sudo yum update && sudo yum install build-essential`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting libstdc++-devel, etc. etc. **c++** : # `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: Yes! I missing a package name "gcc-c++" before. I thought the package "gcc" both contain c lib and c++ lib ... orz